# How to get all possible routes using Google API...?

Tags: ios, api, google-maps, routes, relative-path

I am using following url in for getting routes

http://maps.google.com/maps?output=dragdir&saddr=AddrOflocationA&daddr= AddrOfLocationB
I need to show several paths between two destinations as we see on google maps.

Answer (score 0):

See previous answer here: [Using Google Maps 3 API to get multiple routes on a Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8304875/using-google-maps-3-api-to-get-multiple-routes-on-a-map)

Effectively you'll need to store the results of the routes queries in an array and then render them to the map.